# How to read a file which contains an array and use it in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have the following which works fine.

app.rb

```
require "thor"

class App < Thor

  desc "list_recipes [KEYWORD] [OPTIONS]", "List all recipes. If a keyword is given, it filters the list based off it."
  option :format
  option :show_time, type: :boolean, default: true #--show-time --no-show-time
  def list_recipes keyword=nil
    recipes = [
      {
        title: "Ratatouille",
        cooking_time: "60 min",
        ingredients:  %w(potatoes carrots peppers onions zucchini tomatoes)
      },
      {
        title: "Mac & Cheese",
        cooking_time: "20 min",
        ingredients: %w(macarroni cheese mustard milk)
      },
      {
        title: "Caesar Salad",
        cooking_time: "10 min",
        ingredients:  %w(chicken lettuce croutons eggs)
      }
    ]

    recipes_to_be_listed = if keyword.nil? then recipes
                         else recipes.select { |recipe| recipe[:title].downcase.include? keyword.downcase}
                         end

    recipes_to_be_listed.each do | recipe |
      if options[:format].nil?
        print_default recipe
      else options[:format] == "oneline"
        print_oneline recipe
      end

    end
  end     

  private

  def print_default recipe
    puts "-------------"
    puts "Recipe: #{recipe[:title]}"
    puts "It takes: #{recipe[:cooking_time]} to cook."
    puts "The ingredients are: #{recipe[:ingredients].join(", ")}"
    puts ""
  end

  def print_oneline recipe
    if options[:show_time]
      time = "(#{recipe[:cooking_time]})"
    else
      time = ""
    end

    puts %Q{#{recipe[:title]} #{time}}
  end

end

App.start ARGV
# ARGV is for options, arguments, subcommand to be parsed in app.
```

Now I want to replace recipes by reading this file.

recipes.txt

```
[
  {
    title: "Ratatouille",
    cooking_time: "60 min",
    ingredients:  %w(potatoes carrots peppers onions zucchini tomatoes)
  },
  {
    title: "Mac & Cheese",
    cooking_time: "20 min",
    ingredients: %w(macarroni cheese mustard milk)
  },
  {
    title: "Caesar Salad",
    cooking_time: "10 min",
    ingredients:  %w(chicken lettuce croutons eggs)
  }
]
```

Then I tried the following but it gives an error.

```
def list_recipes keyword=nil
  recipes = File.read('./recipes.txt')
..
```

What is the best way to read a file which contains array and use it?

Comment: Where is that file coming from? Storing data in pure Ruby is not a good idea: You have to do questionable things to recover/reuse it, such as use `eval`, plus you can't easily reuse it in other languages. Instead, store it as YAML, or maybe JSON, where it's easily read and reused. If you have to `eval` it, consider the damage that could be done if someone malicious got access to write that file and put in something destructive to your system. It'd run with the same privileges your code has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't save the data as a Ruby file. Reusing it is much more difficult, plus reloading it opens potential holes in your code that can be exploited if a malicious user gained access to your file-system.

Instead, use something like YAML or JSON to serialize the data, and, at the same time, make it reusable by other languages.

Here's the data:

```
data = [
  {
    title: "Ratatouille",
    cooking_time: "60 min",
    ingredients:  %w(potatoes carrots peppers onions zucchini tomatoes)
  },
  {
    title: "Mac & Cheese",
    cooking_time: "20 min",
    ingredients: %w(macarroni cheese mustard milk)
  },
  {
    title: "Caesar Salad",
    cooking_time: "10 min",
    ingredients:  %w(chicken lettuce croutons eggs)
  }
]
```

Here's how it'd look in YAML:

```
require 'yaml'

puts data.to_yaml

# >> ---
# >> - :title: Ratatouille
# >>   :cooking_time: 60 min
# >>   :ingredients:
# >>   - potatoes
# >>   - carrots
# >>   - peppers
# >>   - onions
# >>   - zucchini
# >>   - tomatoes
# >> - :title: Mac & Cheese
# >>   :cooking_time: 20 min
# >>   :ingredients:
# >>   - macarroni
# >>   - cheese
# >>   - mustard
# >>   - milk
# >> - :title: Caesar Salad
# >>   :cooking_time: 10 min
# >>   :ingredients:
# >>   - chicken
# >>   - lettuce
# >>   - croutons
# >>   - eggs
```

Notice, it's easily read, and easily retrieved using:

```
data = YAML.load_file('path/to/the/data.yaml')
```

It's easily written using:

```
File.write('path/to/the/data.yaml', data.to_yaml)
```

You can use JSON just as well, however YAML tends to be a lot easier to read:

```
require 'json'
# >> [{"title":"Ratatouille","cooking_time":"60 min","ingredients":["potatoes","carrots","peppers","onions","zucchini","tomatoes"]},{"title":"Mac & Cheese","cooking_time":"20 min","ingredients":["macarroni","cheese","mustard","milk"]},{"title":"Caesar Salad","cooking_time":"10 min","ingredients":["chicken","lettuce","croutons","eggs"]}]
```

Here's the same JSON "prettified":

```
puts JSON.pretty_generate(data)
# >> [
# >>   {
# >>     "title": "Ratatouille",
# >>     "cooking_time": "60 min",
# >>     "ingredients": [
# >>       "potatoes",
# >>       "carrots",
# >>       "peppers",
# >>       "onions",
# >>       "zucchini",
# >>       "tomatoes"
# >>     ]
# >>   },
# >>   {
# >>     "title": "Mac & Cheese",
# >>     "cooking_time": "20 min",
# >>     "ingredients": [
# >>       "macarroni",
# >>       "cheese",
# >>       "mustard",
# >>       "milk"
# >>     ]
# >>   },
# >>   {
# >>     "title": "Caesar Salad",
# >>     "cooking_time": "10 min",
# >>     "ingredients": [
# >>       "chicken",
# >>       "lettuce",
# >>       "croutons",
# >>       "eggs"
# >>     ]
# >>   }
# >> ]
```

The JSON can be read and parsed easily also, using something like:

```
data = JSON[File.read('path/to/data.json')]
```

Like YAML, JSON is also easily written to disk:

```
File.write('path/to/data.json', data.to_json)
```

At work, we use YAML for data on disk, and JSON for data we're moving between apps; We find YAML to be more easily read and modified by hand, and JSON to be more efficient across the wire.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to load that file as string and use [eval](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-eval) to evaluate it. But think about security!

```
array = eval(File.read('recipes.txt'))
```

Maybe it will be better idea to [Marshal](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Marshal.html)ize it into file or to do some Factory class to create this.

Or you can hide this structure into some constant into another file and just require that file to get access to that constant.

Comment: Mmmm eval.. I prefer to avoid it.

Comment: @retro your prof picture is funny.. :) Rotate it 90 degree...right!!:)

Comment: "hide this structure into some constant into another file"? What does that help? If someone has access to the code, they have access to all the code, and would have access to the data in no time. Security by obscurity is a waste of time.

Comment: the Tin Man: you've missed whole point!
It's only code cleanup. Read app.rb from question and read my answer. It is only hidding that structure to avoid mess in Thor script, and not to improve security. There's nothing about security in question. So I'm not sure what are you writting about :(

Answer (score 0):

You are already using a text file that is structured, so you might as well just go all the way.

recipe.txt can look like this:

```
@recipes = 
[
  {
    title: "Ratatouille",
    cooking_time: "60 min",
    ingredients:  %w(potatoes carrots peppers onions zucchini tomatoes)
  },
  {
    title: "Mac & Cheese",
    cooking_time: "20 min",
    ingredients: %w(macarroni cheese mustard milk)
  },
  {
    title: "Caesar Salad",
    cooking_time: "10 min",
    ingredients:  %w(chicken lettuce croutons eggs)
  }
]
```

And your code can look like this:

```
load './recipe.txt'
```

And you will be able to access that instance variable.

So, if you are going to use a structured file anyway, you may as well use Ruby.  Until you need some "advantage" from using some kind of marshaling tool such as YAML or anything else, you really don't need it.

Here is the IRB Session I used to ensure code:

```
>> load 'recipe.txt'                                                          
=> true                                                                       
>> @recipe                                                                    
=> nil                                                                        
>> @recipes                                                                   
=> [{:title=>"Ratatouille", :cooking_time=>"60 min", :ingredients=>["potatoes"
, "carrots", "peppers", "onions", "zucchini", "tomatoes"]}, {:title=>"Mac & Ch
eese", :cooking_time=>"20 min", :ingredients=>["macarroni", "cheese", "mustard
", "milk"]}, {:title=>"Caesar Salad", :cooking_time=>"10 min", :ingredients=>[
"chicken", "lettuce", "croutons", "eggs"]}]
```

`load` will work, `require` works differently and so will not work for this solution.

As shown in this `test.rb` file:

```
load './recipe.txt'
puts @recipes

# >> {:title=>"Ratatouille", :cooking_time=>"60 min", :ingredients=>["potatoes", "carrots", "peppers", "onions", "zucchini", "tomatoes"]}
# >> {:title=>"Mac & Cheese", :cooking_time=>"20 min", :ingredients=>["macarroni", "cheese", "mustard", "milk"]}
# >> {:title=>"Caesar Salad", :cooking_time=>"10 min", :ingredients=>["chicken", "lettuce", "croutons", "eggs"]}
```

Comment: It gives error "app1a.rb:19:in `list_recipes': undefined local variable or method `recipes' for #<App:0x007fbcfc08ac30> (NameError) ..."

Comment: I don't know what line 19 refers to, but you may have to adjust it.  Updated the IRB session used to test this.

Comment: Of course, if you change the extension, then 'require' will work.  And I did not show puts @recipe.inspect, but if I had  you would see that it is an array with the hashes at each index.